# auto add comments in the header

Tags: svn, svn-propset

With SVN, is it possible to incude automaticlly a "comment" tempate when I add a new file ?

For example, I want to add **automatically** this comment when I add a file "*.pl" :

```
# SVN information :
#  @Autor : $Author$
#  @Autor : $Revision$
#  @Id : $Id$
#  @Date : $Date$
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion does not have this functionality. You can create a pre-commit hook script to check for the existence of this block and reject a commit which contains a `.pl` file but lacks the block, but with SVN alone you cannot automatically add content as you describe.